# Smarty: Create png image from html/php

Tags: php, html, image, smarty, smarty2

I’m using Smarty to build an article layout with a pull quote, styled using webfonts. I want create a parallel layout for email clients which automatically includes a png version of the pull quote.

Is there a way to write a png image to file based on the snippet of code I use to format the pull quote for the article layout, the same way I might write an html file from a Smarty template?

This is my snippet code:

```
<p class="quote" style="width:720px; color: #ff0066;font-family: {$quotes.0.fontfamily};font-size: {$quotes.0.size}px;text-indent: -12px; margin: 0 20px 0.5em 20px;">{$quotes.0.quote}</p>
```

This is how I imagine an output might function:

```
// get output 
$output = $smarty->fetch('quote-image.tpl'); 
// write png image file
$file = $quotes["filename"].'.png';
file_put_contents($file,$output);
```

But clearly it’s not that simple!

Comment: HTML to image doesn't have any decent solutions - you would have more luck with PDF instead. dompdf for example.

Comment: Okay, thanks, understood. As an alternative, are there options for using CSS styles to work with a PHP solution like the one here: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php

Comment: You can generate pdf and convert pdf to png with imagemagick.